# How can I scale Botkit application

Tags: botkit

I new to botkit. Still exploring the framework.

How does the botkit scale? Can I set up multiple server and route request randomly? Will the context be preserved if each user requests end up in different server?

Answer (score 0):

Saving the session into dbs is the only way to go ahead, Botkit does not support it by default.
 There are other people trying to solve similar problem, this might help https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/251